# Manejo de interface con hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

Hola mi problema es que no se como implementar el mapeo en XML con una interfaz entre medio paso a explicar

[image: este es mi diagrama de clases]

IProducto es mi interfaz y la usa para poder filtrar y tener una unica opcion de seleccion que puede ser plato o producto(bebidas) o vianda o un menu predefinido. Mi problema es que a la hora de mapear no se como hacerlo
Intente hacer mi der asi pero tmp se como mapearlo
[image: a]

Saludos.

Comment: Ya intentaste convertir la interfaz en clase?? si no agregas variables y solo métodos se sigue comportando como una interfaz, pero ya podrías usarla con herencia en hibernate

Comment: entiendo a lo que vas pero entonces tendria que crear una entidad vacia llamada IProducto en la base de datos y ahi mapear la herencia pero no se si eso se puede hacer pero voy a probar muchas gracias

Comment: Creo que antes de hacer ER deberías hacer una jerarquía de herencia de Productos y las clases que derivan de el. Teniendo ese diagrama es mas sencillo pasarlo a ER, porque a mi punto de vista IProducto no debería existir. Revisa este tutorial que ya es algo viejo, igual ya no funciona, pero lo importante son los conceptos de herencia en hibernate (Tabla por jerarquía de clases [Tabla unica], Tabla para cada clase [joins], Una Tabla por clase concreta [tablas sueltas] ) y tu estas tratando de hace la segunda opción: joins http://www.javatutoriales.com/2010/08/hibernate-parte-10-herencia.html

Comment: Para mi no deberia existir en DER pero no sabiamos como hacer asi que hicimos herencia y y creamos una entidad para la entidad padre no me parece optimo que este la entidad pero fue una forma simple de hacerlo y no tener problemas de mapeo con hibernate. Muchas gracias por todo